# Как сделать изменения значения первой таблицы в бд после выбора select и отправки запроса?

Tags: запрос, mysqli, php, mysql

```
<?
$res = DB::_()->query("SELECT users.id,users.ip,
            users.login,users.fio,users.date_birth,
            users.email,users.active,users.date_reg,gr_user.Name_gr 
        FROM users INNER JOIN gr_user ON users.gr_id=gr_user.gr_id");
while($pole = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){?>
<div class='users'>
<span style='width:65px;height:35px;'><? echo $pole['id']?></span>
<span style='width:75px;height:35px;'><? echo $pole['ip']?></span>
<span style='width:105px;height:35px;'><?echo $pole['Name_gr']?>
<form action='/index.php?module=users&page=update_users' method='POST'>
<select name='name_gr' id='name_gr'>
<?
$res2= DB::_()->query("SELECT gr_user.gr_id,gr_user.Name_gr from gr_user");
while($pole2 = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)){?>
<option value='<? echo $pole2['gr_id']?>'><? echo $pole2['Name_gr']?></option><br />
<?}?>
</select>
</span>
<span style='width:75px;height:35px;'><? echo $pole['login']?></span>
<span style='width:135px;height:35px;'><? echo $pole['fio']?></span>
<span style='width:65px;height:35px;'><? echo $pole['date_birth']?></span>
<span style='width:155px;height:35px;'><? echo $pole['email']?></span>
<span style='width:65px;height:35px;'><? echo $pole['active']?></span>
<span style='width:65px;height:35px;'><? echo $pole['date_reg']?></span>
    </div>
    <?}?>
    <input id='' type='submit' name='update' value='Изменить' />
    </form>
```

Выводим информацию из первой таблицы БД: id,ip,gr_id,login и так далее.
Рядом с Групповой идентификации выводим select из второй таблицы перечисляем имеющиеся Name_gr(т.е. Пользователь,Модератор,Администратор.)

1)Выбираем Name_gr из select и нажимаем на кнопку изменить. То есть например с Пользователя хотим сделать Модератора.
2)Данные отправлены.
Проблема: Не совсем понимаю как обновить данные gr_id после нажатия Изменить у определенного пользователя.
Пытался сделать так

```
$res3= DB::_()->query("UPDATE users SET users.gr_id='".$pole2['gr_id']."' WHERE users.id='".pole['id']."'");
```

// Но тут неправильно.

Comment: Вы скобку не закрыли в последнем примере кода

Comment: Не,не в этом проблема.Спасибо,тут исправлю..Там скобка у меня  в update.php закрыта.

Answer (score 1):

Сам принцип я не понял оказывается..Пришел к пониманию и решению.
Вот решение.

```
<?
$res = DB::_()->query("SELECT users.id,users.ip,
users.login,users.fio,users.date_birth,
users.email,users.active,users.date_reg,gr_user.Name_gr 
FROM users INNER JOIN gr_user ON users.gr_id=gr_user.gr_id");
while($pole = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){?>
<form action='/index.php?module=users&page=update_users' method='POST'>
<div class='users'>
<span style='width:65px;height:35px;'><? echo $pole['id']?></span>
<span style='width:75px;height:35px;'><? echo $pole['ip']?></span>
<span style='width:115px;height:35px;'><?echo $pole['Name_gr']?>
<select name='name_gr' id='name_gr'>
<?
$res2= DB::_()->query("SELECT gr_user.gr_id,gr_user.Name_gr from gr_user");
while($pole2 = mysqli_fetch_array($res2)){?>
<option value='<? echo $pole2['gr_id']?>'><? echo $pole2['Name_gr']?></option>
<?}?>
</select>
</span>
<span style='width:75px;height:35px;'><? echo $pole['login']?></span>
<span style='width:135px;height:35px;'><? echo $pole['fio']?></span>
<span style='width:65px;height:35px;'><? echo $pole['date_birth']?></span>
<span style='width:155px;height:35px;'><? echo $pole['email']?></span>
<span style='width:65px;height:35px;'><? echo $pole['active']?></span>
<span style='width:65px;height:35px;'><? echo $pole['date_reg']?></span>
    </div>
    <?}?>

<input id='' type='submit' name='update' value='Изменить' />
    </form>

$sel = $_POST['name_gr'];
$res3 = DB::_()->query("UPDATE users SET users.gr_id ='".$sel."'");
header('Location: /index.php?module=users&page=list_users');
```

P.s. Надеюсь, поможет тем, кто не понял сам принцип.